# How to derive the Lorentz Invariant bilinear form in the $(1/2, 1/2)$ representation?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, invariants

We can represent the complexified proper Lorentz group Lie algebra as the direct sum $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$. The representation nomenclature is $(n,m)$, two half integer numbers giving the spin of the left and right element of the sum.

The $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation of an element of the proper Lorentz group is $$D_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}} (\vec{\theta},\vec{\beta} )= exp[\vec{\theta}.\vec{S}(R) + \vec{\beta}.\vec{S}(K)].$$ $\vec{\theta}$ and $\vec{\beta}$ are the six parameters of the Lorentz group. $\vec{S}(R)$ and $\vec{S}(K)$ are the  $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation of the generators of rotations and boosts.

The $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation is four dimensional and therefore the elements of the vector space it acts on are column matrix with four components (let's call them $\Phi$). We then have $$\Phi \rightarrow D_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}} (\vec{\theta},\vec{\beta} ) \Phi .$$

How do I construct the Lorentz invariant bilinear form now? I know it is the 4-vector representation and that I simply need to add the Minkowski metric but how am I supposed to derive that from here?  Should I explicitly derive $\vec{S}(R)$ and $\vec{S}(K)$ and then show their relationships with the Minkowski metric?